# Umbraco - Install packages

Tags: umbraco

I'm new to Umbraco and I'm try to install some packages from the Umbraco package Repository. I'm getting a 500 - Internal server error in the Umbraco CMS when trying to browse the packages. First I thought I did something wrong in my installation of Umbraco but when I look at the source code it looks like packages.umbraco.org are having problems. Can anyone confirm if they having the same problem?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm no expert, but is your file permissions correctly set?

Comment: I have tried giving NETWORK_SERVICE and IIS_IUSRS full permissions to c:\windows\temp and the root directory and also different IIS identity settings without any luck.

Answer (score 2):

Download the packages from our.umbraco.org and install as a local package. If that doesn't work then it may be permissions. If you aren't able to download packages on our.umbraco.org, then the package server may be down.

Answer (score 1):

First of all either check the logs or change the customErrors section of your web.config so that you can see more details on the error.

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

I have on a few rare occasions installed a version of Umbraco where I think the installedPackages.config file was empty and without at least an empty `<packages />` node it generates an error. Check the file looks like this as a minimum:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages />
```

You will usually find the file located in **App_Data\packages\installed\installedPackages.config** however I think this may have changed in more recent versions of Umbraco.

Answer (score 0):

Some good tips already, so I'll add a less likely one!

I have seen this error when I've first installed and for some reason the .net worker process has crashed so the internal error is simply that the site can't find cassini (or IIS depending on your settings).

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps there is nothing wrong and it is in fact related to the current issue with the Umbraco servers:

> ICYMI: Our ISP have issues with their virtualisation platform and it affects > http://umbraco.com , umbraco.tv, Our Umbraco and package repo.

https://twitter.com/umbraco/statuses/293297374271533056